# Modern iptables syntax for specifying a new connection

Tags: iptables

I'm new to iptables and confused by the CLI changes over the years. I see many examples which seem to do the same thing but with different syntax.

Are these the *same exactly*, or is there some nuance between them:

- `-p tcp -m state --state NEW`
- `-p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW`
- `-p tcp -m tcp --syn` / `-p tcp --syn`

If they are the same exactly, I'll use `-p tcp --syn`, which would simplify  / shorten my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man iptables-extensions`:

> #### state
>
> The "state" extension is a subset of the "conntrack" module. "state" allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet.
>
> [!] --state state
>
> where state is a comma separated list of the connection states to match. Only a subset of the states unterstood by "conntrack" are recognized: INVALID, ESTABLISHED, NEW, RELATED or UNTRACKED. For their description, see the "conntrack" heading in this manpage.

[...]

> #### conntrack
>
> This module, when combined with connection tracking, allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet/connection.
>
> [!] --ctstate statelist
>
> statelist is a comma separated list of the connection states to match. Possible states are listed below.
> [...]

[...]

> #### tcp
>
> These extensions can be used if `--protocol tcp' is specified. It provides the following options:
>
> [!] --syn
>
> Only match TCP packets with the SYN bit set and the ACK,RST and FIN bits cleared. Such packets are used to request TCP connection initiation; for example, blocking such packets coming in an interface will prevent incoming TCP connections, but outgoing TCP connections will be unaffected.

So the first two are equivalent, the last does something different (you can use it to **block** TCP connection attempts, for example).

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand though why `--syn` is different - when I read that man page I assumed it did the same as the others. It's the first packer in a new connection.

Comment: "Connection" isn't restricted to TCP. And one variant directly inspects the TCP packet, the other two variant use the connection tracker (so the module is loaded). In particular, if you want to allow TCP connections, and not only block the first packet, you need the connection tracker.

Comment: "...if you want to allow TCP connections, and not only block the first packet, you need the connection tracker..." - I don't follow... can't I allow / block using the first two commands (via connection tracker) as well?

Comment: What happens to the other packets of a TCP connection if you only care about the first packet in your firewall? In particular, what happens to spoofed packets?